# Maven cannot find a package with jpa entities

Tags: java, maven, continuous-integration

I'm trying to build up application that operates as shelter service. I have 3 micro services: one (external-service) contains external interfaces such as controllers and authorization logic and cats & owners services provide access to my entities. There is also a module that contains all jpa entities and dtos. Communication between micro services takes place via RabbitMQ. As database I use postgres. When I run my program locally, it works perfectly fine, but when I try to push it on github it fails with error "package %package with jpa entities% does not exist". In services, dependency on the module with entities was added, in code the package was imported.

Here is my pom file for one of the services that uses package with jpa entities:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <artifactId>owner-service</artifactId>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.pllenxx</groupId>
            <artifactId>models</artifactId>
            <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <parent>
        <groupId>com.pllenxx</groupId>
        <artifactId>shelter-service</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>
    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>19</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>19</maven.compiler.target>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.22.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <skipTests>true</skipTests>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

I have tried to reassign the packages, invalidate caches, change application structure (at first all of my modules had `org.springframework.boot` as parent, then I made it parent for my root pom and my other services were inherited from root), change CI, but it didn't work

Comment: Use `mvn dependency:tree` and check that the dependency is actually in your dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you have deployed your 'models' module as a jar file in an artifactory or another storage. To include this in your build, you need to add information about the repository where your shared modules are kept. For example:

```
<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>maven</id>
        <url>https://your-art.com/artifactory/maven/</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>
```

Ensure that you set any necessary mirrors in your settings.xml:

```
<settings>
    <mirrors>
        <mirror>
            <id>Artifactory</id>
            <name>Maven mirror</name>
            <url>https://yourart.com/artifactory/maven</url>
            <mirrorOf>external:*</mirrorOf> <!-- This will redirect all external repository requests to the specified mirror -->
        </mirror>
    </mirrors>
    <servers>
        <server>
            <id>maven</id>
            <username>maven-ro</username>
            <password>${password}</password> <!-- Use environment variables -->
        </server>
    </servers>
</settings>
```

Hope it helps.